# How can I download geo-tagged videos for a particular region from Instagram/Vine/Youtube?

Tags: video, youtube, instagram-api, geotagging, vine

I want to download lots of short geo-tagged videos. i.e., given a location query, download all videos in that area automatically. I haven’t found any promising library/API to do that. Vine/Instagram/Twitter/Youtube, any data source will be fine, as long as the video is geo-tagged. Thanks a lot.

PS: a sample starter script may help more. I have checked python-instagram, vivo, etc., but their documentation are not detailed enough.